# Reference Request: investigation of higher order dynamical systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems, control-theory

In dynamical system and control theory, people usually investigate into system of the type $$\dot x = f(x,u)$$

Is there any references to looks into the theory of higher order dynamical systems of the type $${\ddot x} = f(x,u)$$
$$\vdots$$
$${x}^n = f(x,u)$$

and so on?

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this where you can just "vectorize" everything and get it to be a first order vector valued ODE?

Comment: Exactly as Eric said: if $\ddot{x} = f(x,u)$ then define $y = \dot{x}$ to get it on the form $\dot{y} = f(x,u)$, $\dot{x} = y$. If you want you can combine $(x,y)=X$ into a single vector (and similar for the right hand side) which allows you to write the system on the standard form: $\dot{X} = F(X,u)$.

Comment: @Winther Hi sorry in my notation my $\dot x$ is your $\dot X$, I am assuming that we already put all those little $x, y$s in a $\dot x$, I wonder if there is study on properties of (using your notation) $\ddot X = F(X,u)$

Comment: My notation is equally bad, but it applies also when $x,y$ are vectors. Say that $x=(x_1,x_2)$ so that your system written out reads  $\ddot{x}_1 = f_1(x_1,x_2,u)$ and $\ddot{x}_2 = f_2(x_1,x_2,u)$. Then define $x_3 = \dot{x_1}$ and $x_4 = \dot{x_2}$ to get the system $\dot{x_1} = x_3, \dot{x_2} = x_4, \dot{x_3} = f_1(x_1,x_2,u)$ and $\dot{x_4} = f_2(x_1,x_2,u)$. Now with $\vec{X} = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ and $\vec{F} = (x_3,x_4, f_1, f_2)$ you can write $\dot{\vec{X}} = \vec{F}(\vec{X},u)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

any equation of the form 
$$
x^{(n)}=f(t,x,x',x'',\cdots,x^{(n-1)})
$$
can be reduced to a system of first order:
$$
\begin{cases}
x'=x_1\\
x_1'=x_2\\
x_2'=x_3\\
\cdots\\
x_{n-2}'=x_{n-1}\\
x_{n-1}'=f(t,x,x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1})
\end{cases}
$$